# OnCollisionExit2D not working in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Hi I'm trying to make an object passable whenever the player passes it from the bottom but solid when it is on top of it. The thing is that when the player touches the object from the bottom everything works just as it should, but when it exits the collider the object won't turn into a solid again.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Passable" && hasGoneThrough == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("collided");
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Passable")
    {
        Debug.Log("uncollided");
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: because the object is now a trigger not a collider?

Comment: And string literal as `tag` is worst way to compare, a typo provocateur.

Answer (score 0):

"Oncollision" is literally works when different colliders physically collide.
if you want to call a functions when passing through an object. use "OntriggerEnter".
before use it please check "isTrigger" on your collider inspecter
I'm not sure it work on 2d. I try only 3d
I hope its working.